# Which node from TreeView is selected (PySide)?

Tags: python, pyside, qtreeview

I have a program with QTreeView and I want to disable/enable some actions in Toolbar depending on which node is selected but I don't know how to get selected node. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following example I show how to know which items are selected in a QTreeView, for this we use the selectionChanged signal that returns the selected and deselected items, then iterates and obtains the QModelIndex, and through this and the model we obtain the data.

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class Main(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        QTreeView.__init__(self)
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath(QDir.homePath())
        self.setModel(model)
        m = self.selectionModel()
        m.selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

    def onSelectionChanged(self, selected, deselected):
        for index in selected.indexes():
            print(self.model().data(index))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```